# How to delete certain file extensions in a specified folder recursive in Git

Tags: git, recursion

Does anyone know the alternative command line for this in the git command window?

```
del *.orig /s
```

(so delete all files with the extension .orig recursive)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're running in windows?  If you're using git bash, you can do:

```
find -name *.orig | xargs rm
```

Comment: `find -name *.orig -delete`

Comment: @aragaer That works for me in linux, but I couldn't get it to work in 'git bash' for some reason, so I provided the command above instead.

Answer (score 3):

you dont have to use xargs to accomplish this...

`find . -name *.orig -exec git rm -r --cached {} \;`

Comment: Hello all the commands above did not work for me.  I had to put quotes around the file extension like this  `find . -name '*.orig' `  But I could not delete the files using this command:
`find . -name '*.orig' -delete `  
  
Does anyone know why?

Comment: the quoting issue is dependent on which shell you use.  the -delete flag will remove the files from your system, not git. that's why i suggested using the -exec flag with git rm -r --cached, which will recursively remove the files both locally, in git's work tree, and it's cache.